# How to present a review paper at a conference?

Tags: conference, presentation, literature-review

I sent an abstract of a review paper for oral presentation to a conference, and it was accepted. The presentation will be about the most important developments and contributions made in the last decade on my specific area of research. Now I am preparing the speech, but I am not sure how to give a 12-minutes speech about all the work that has been done (it's a lot). Can someone give some suggestions on how to do a nice presentation about a review paper?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In 12 minutes, the best you can do for your audience is highlight four to six broad observations or conclusions about the state of research. Here are some questions you might address with your observations:

- Are the lines of research diverging and multiplying, or converging and consolidating?
- Has it divided into "factions" or "schools" that define problems, methods, and solutions differently?  Or is all research operating under a single paradigm?
- What's the influence and interaction with other fields and disciplines?
- Where has research made progress addressing fundamental questions?  Where has research made no meaningful progress?
- Where should researchers look for the most promising research directions and under-explored areas?

Don't try to make more than six observations in 12 minutes. By trying to say more, you are actually communicating less effectively.  Any one who wants the full story can read your paper.